# Can updating SQL Server Management Studio result in data loss?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update SQL Server Management Studio to a newer version, but I'm concerned that doing so might cause me to lose data in my database. Is this something that can happen during the update process?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can drop a database using any version of SSMS from  Object Explorer or a `DROP DATABASE` command from a query window. You must, of course, have permissions to do so and have exclusive access to the database.

Comment: Are you asking us if SQL Server Management Studio can drop a database?  If so, then yes: Right click the database name under the Databases nodes and select Delete.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question to make it easier to read. If I've misunderstood what you're asking, you can reject the edit.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is different and SQL server is different.if u updated SSMS nothing will haapen to SQL Server Databases.

Answer (score 0):

Updating SQL Server Management Studio will have no impact on your database what so ever. They are completely separate tools with separate installations so there will be no impact for data integrity or the functioning of your SQL Server. SSMS will only allow you to access, configure and work with your SQL Server engine and data. So no, updating SSMS will not delete your database.

But do pay attention to the fact that a server reboot might be required and that is always something to do with great care.